# Cannot ALTER column in HBase

Tags: hbase

This is a newbie HBase question. I have a table in HBase (1.2.6):

```
hbase(main):042:0> create 'ship', 'cf1'
0 row(s) in 1.2200 seconds
=> Hbase::Table - ship
```

It is created:

```
hbase(main):046:0> desc 'ship'
Table ship is ENABLED
ship
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'cf1', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false',
 KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', 
TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
1 row(s) in 0.0110 seconds
```

But I cannot alter it:

```
hbase(main):047:0> alter 'ship', NAME=>'cf1', VERSIONS=>5
Unknown argument ignored: cf1
Unknown argument ignored: VERSIONS
Updating all regions with the new schema...
1/1 regions updated.
Done.
0 row(s) in 1.8710 seconds
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the problem after some experimentation. The default value of **hbase.column.max.version** in *hbase-site.xml* is 1. Apparently if it stays like this, all attempts to set a higher number of versions fail with cryptic errors.
Setting this parameter to a value bigger than 1 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but found a different solution. I actually did not find the config in hbase-site.xml.

My solution was to first disable the table before altering it.
Once disabled, I was able to change the # versions.